# Share data between Office Web Add-ins

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I would like to share a value between different Office Web Add-ins within the same Office 365/Exchange account. I need a kind of storage that would be available in all the user Add-ins, in all type of supported apps (both desktop and web).

The goal is to keep user login session that when user logs in to my service in one of my Add-ins (let's say in Outlook), he will be logged in Word Add-in as well.

Are there any tools to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting ask. As such as there is no store to host add-in specific session information at O365 level. Office add-ins for the most part supports single sign-on across apps. Perhaps, you could maintain the user session information on your backend and recognize their next sign-on on different app/device based on previous auth to your backend (e.g., UserA from O365 tenant accesses your add-in on Outlook and add-in prompts userA to sign-on to your system. Now user-A accesses your add-in on Word and based on O365 single sign-on you can skip the secondary auth to your backend and let the user through).

Comment: that what I was planing to do if could not share the security token (or other data) between add-ins. So as I understand, there is no way to pass any variables?

Comment: No, not through any formal APIs. It'll be custom implementation on the add-ins part.